# Authenticated routes in reactJS using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**Description::**

I am working on reactJS app and using [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) for routing. If user is not authenticate, it's go to "http://localhost:3000/login" and after successful login it's redirects to " http://localhost:3000/dashboard". After reloading this page it's shows me blank page.

To resolve this problem I have added "/app" after my base url, and now it comes before every routing url now  inner pages routing is like "http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard".
But I don't want to add "app" before every routing element, 
I need routing url should be, base_url/page routing path.

**Blank page routing::**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const InitialPath = ({ component: Component, authUser, ...rest }) => {
   return (<Route
         {...rest}
         render={props =>
            authUser
               ? <Component {...props} />
               :
               <Redirect
                  to={{
                     pathname: '/login',
                     state: { from: props.location }
                  }}
               />
         }
      />
   )
}

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   render() {
      let isUserLogggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isUserLoggedIn');
      const { location, match } = this.props;
      let url = location.pathname.split('/');
      if (location.pathname === '/login') {
         localStorage.clear();
      }
      if (location.pathname === '/') {
         if (!isUserLogggedIn) {
            return (<Redirect exact from='/' to={`${match.url}login`} />);
         } else {
            return (<Redirect exact from='/' to={`${match.url}app`} />);
         }
      }
      if ((url[1] !== "app") && (url[1] !== "login")) {
         return (<Redirect exact from={location.pathname} to={`${match.url}login`} />);
      }
      return (
         <>
            <BrowserRouter>
               <Switch>
                  <InitialPath
                     path={`${match.url}app`}
                     authUser={isUserLogggedIn}
                     component={DefaultLayout}
                     location={location}
                  />
                  <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
               </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
         </>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

If the "app" is removed from root, then its work continues and error appears.

**ERROR::**

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem not with urls.

Trying to handle `localStorage` stuff into a `render` method is not the best idea. You should use life-cycle-methods for it i.e. `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`.

Your `App` component seems to be overwhelmed by logic. The auth-logic should be into the `Login` component, when it (`Login`) mounts it should clear storage. When user successfully authenticates, it (`Login`) should save the session id to the storage.

The next thing is messing with locations by yourself is not necessary, let `react-router` to do it for you.

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate () {
    this.setState({ isUserLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("isUserLoggedIn") });
  }

  render () {
    const { isUserLogggedIn } = this.state;

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <InitialPath
            path="/dashboard"
            authUser={isUserLogggedIn}
            component={DefaultLayout}
            location={location}
          />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

class Login extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    localStorage.removeItem("isUserLogggedIn");
  }

  render () {
    // some render stuff
    //
    // after successfull login
    // you should save `isUserLogggedIn` into localStorage 
    // and redirect to the main page
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented this, but its shows error:Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Oh, of course, you should check the previous props and state and the new ones to prevent cycle updates.

Comment: Here I've answered a similar question a moments ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877684/component-rendering-too-early/55878082#55878082

Comment: I have try this, but its not working. Same problem: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops